# Where does ubuntu store media codecs?

Tags: 20.04, codecs

I have installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras` to get the media codecs. I was wondering where does these codecs are stored after installtion? Can anyone help with the location?

Answer (score 2):

This package is a stub, it installs the [dependent packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-restricted-extras) from dependent and recommended packages:

- ubuntu-restricted-addons

  - chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
  - gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3
  - gstreamer1.0-libav
  - gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
  - gstreamer1.0-vaapi
- libavcodec-extra
- ttf-mscorefonts-installer
- unrar

Each package has its filelist (`unrar` [as example](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/unrar/filelist)) and also maybe checked locally with `dpkg` (`dpkg -L unrar` as example).

Comment: I am actually trying to copy the codecs to a different location. Is there anyway I can download them separately and place it where I want? For example, let's say I want hvec and aac codec, how can I download those separately?

Comment: You have to analyze their packages and try to install only them. Installing separate files without using package manager is non-standard, not reproducible, as you will lose control on them.